# Texture library on iOS. Cannot change masked corners

Tags: ios, textures, cornerradius

Help me please)
I can't change maskedcorner to ASDisplayNode.

There's three mode of cornerRoundingType: ASCornerRoundingTypeClipping, ASCornerRoundingTypePrecomposited, ASCornerRoundingTypeDefaultSlowCALayer
Second just remove all corners from node. Third does nothing, all rounding corners are visible. First doing right corners rounded but also remain on back sharp corners with less alpha. I don't know how to round corners only that I need. Thanks for any help.